# Restore redirection of output streams in bash

Tags: bash, logging

I have a script named `run.sh` and another script named `download-and-run.sh` which downloads something and then calls the first one. I may also call `run.sh` independently.

I want to print timestamp of each message logged to the stdout/stderr when running these scripts. To do so, I added `exec > >(ts '[%R:%S %x %Z]') 2>&1` in the beginning of both of the scripts. Then, when I call `download-and-run.sh` it prints the date twice, which is expected.

It's worth to mention that I need to use `set -x` to track the variables, etc. for debugging purposes. For the record, `help set` says:

> -x  Print commands and their arguments as they are executed.

Let's say these are my files:

`run.sh`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
exec > >(ts '[%R:%S %x %Z]') 2>&1
set -x
echo Hi from run.sh
```

`download-and-run.sh`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
exec > >(ts '[%R:%S %x %Z]') 2>&1
set -x
echo This is a curl command
./run.sh
```

I get this output when running `download-and-run.sh` (Note the bash prompt (`$`) before starting printing timestamps; I guess it may indicate something):

```
$ ./download-and-run.sh
$ [19:40:48 04/21/2022 EDT] + echo This is a curl command
[19:40:48 04/21/2022 EDT] This is a curl command
[19:40:48 04/21/2022 EDT] + ./run.sh
[19:40:48 04/21/2022 EDT] ++ exec
[19:40:48 04/21/2022 EDT] +++ ts '[%R:%S %x %Z]'
[19:40:48 04/21/2022 EDT] [19:40:48 04/21/2022 EDT] ++ echo Hi from run.sh
[19:40:48 04/21/2022 EDT] [19:40:48 04/21/2022 EDT] Hi from run.sh
```

---

To solve having two timestamps, I found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80988/343873) answer to revert back the original stdout/stderr streams in `download-and-run.sh` just before calling `./run.sh` so that the double piping to `ts` is fixed, but the following modified version will strangely print calling `./run.sh` at the first of the output like it's called before anything.

Modified `download-and-run.sh`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
exec 3>&1 4>&2  # Saving stdout and stderr in fd=3,4
exec > >(ts '[%R:%S %x %Z]') 2>&1
set -x
echo This is a curl command
exec >&3 2>&4  # Reverting back normal stdout and stderr from pipe
./run.sh
```

This is the output (Again, note the bash prompt (`$`) before starting printing timestamps; I guess it may indicate something):

```
$ ./download-and-run.sh
+ ./run.sh
++ exec
+++ ts '[%R:%S %x %Z]'
$ [19:42:32 04/21/2022 EDT] + echo This is a curl command
[19:42:32 04/21/2022 EDT] This is a curl command
[19:42:32 04/21/2022 EDT] + exec
[19:42:32 04/21/2022 EDT] ++ echo Hi from run.sh
[19:42:32 04/21/2022 EDT] Hi from run.sh
```

This output has two problems:

1. It doesn't have timestamps in some of the messages.
2. It prints some commands out of order of their execution.

How can I fix them to have only a single timestamp printed before logs when I call `download-and-run.sh`?

---

Here's what I expect to have (there may be some commands added in the scripts to fix the issue which may be printed because of `set -x` and it's okay):

```
$ ./download-and-run.sh
[19:40:48 04/21/2022 EDT] + echo This is a curl command
[19:40:48 04/21/2022 EDT] This is a curl command
[19:40:48 04/21/2022 EDT] + ./run.sh
[19:40:48 04/21/2022 EDT] ++ echo Hi from run.sh
[19:40:48 04/21/2022 EDT] Hi from run.sh
```

and for `run.sh` solely:

```
$ ./run.sh
[19:40:48 04/21/2022 EDT] + echo Hi from run.sh
[19:40:48 04/21/2022 EDT] Hi from run.sh
```

Comment: please update the question to include the expected output for both sets of scripts

Comment: @markp-fuso Hi. I added the expected outputs at the end of my post.

Comment: based solely on what's been provided ... it appears the only lines to be prefixed with a timestamp are the `echo ... ` commands and if this is correct for the real script then I'd probably forego the io redirtions and just replace each `echo` with a custom function (`echots`?) that prefixes the output with a timestamp; or do you also want other non-echo output (not demonstrated in this question) prefixed with a timestamp? (and if so, are said outputs occurring in both scripts)

Comment: @markp-fuso Thanks. Yes, there are other non-echo commands in both of the scripts and I want to log all of them prefixed with timestamp. Sorry if only using `echo` induced such assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an environment variable to determine if timestamps are already enabled. e.g.:

`run.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ -z "${TIMESTAMPS_ENABLED}" ]; then
  exec > >(ts '[%R:%S %x %Z]') 2>&1
fi
set -x
echo Hi from run.sh
```

`download-and-run.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
exec > >(ts '[%R:%S %x %Z]') 2>&1
export TIMESTAMPS_ENABLED="YES"
set -x
echo This is a curl command
./run.sh
```

To answer your question about "out of sequence" printing, You have to understand how the scripts make use of child processes to do the work. Hopefully this diagram will help:

```
Process
1        Start "download_and_run.sh"
1        Redirect output
  2        Start "ts '[%R:%S %x %Z]'" (this takes some time)
1        set -x
1        echo This is a curl command (trace & output sent to Process 2)
1        Undo redirection
1        ./run.sh (trace sent to console)
    3        Start "./run.sh"
1        Wait for Process 3 to finish
    3        Redirect output (trace sent to console)
      4        Start "ts '[%R:%S %x %Z]'" (takes some time & trace sent to console)
    3        set -x
    3        echo Hi from run.sh (trace & output sent to Process 4)
    3        exit
1        exit
  2        write output to console
  2        exit
      4      write output to console
      4      exit
```

This gives the following output from each process:

```
Process
1       + ./run.sh
3       ++ exec
4       +++ ts '[%R:%S %x %Z]'
  At this point, process 3 and process 4 exit, returning a prompt to the user
        $
2       [19:42:32 04/21/2022 EDT] + echo This is a curl command
2       [19:42:32 04/21/2022 EDT] This is a curl command
   Process 2 exits
4       [19:42:32 04/21/2022 EDT] + exec
4       [19:42:32 04/21/2022 EDT] ++ echo Hi from run.sh
4       [19:42:32 04/21/2022 EDT] Hi from run.sh
   Process 4 exits
```

It is important to realize that the two 'ts' commands run in separate processes and take some time to initialize. Process 1 and Process 2 write their output to a pipe and do not wait for the other end to read that output. So they can each exit before the process at the other end of their pipe has finished initializing.

Run_and_download.sh does wait for run.sh to finish, but not the 'ts' command.

Comment: Oh, My, God! There's a real magic in simple thinking, and you're the today's magician. Thanks!

Comment: However, before marking your answer as accepted, do you have any idea why that `./run.sh` is printed before anything in my attempt to restore streams?

Comment: Basically because `> >(ts  '[%R:%S %x %Z]')` results in a new process to run the `ts` command, but the calling script does not wait for that process to finish when it ends. I'll attempt a clearer explanation in my original answer.